# How to prevent the table from alerting the same record twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a have a table created in JavaScript. On button click it is supposed to bring the row id of that row, but when the button is clicked, the row id gets alerted twice.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD('<button type="button" value="Print" class="btnprint" onclick="test(this)">', null);

function test() {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var row  = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
        alert(row);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using inline onclick to bind onclick event??? Anyway, you are passing `this`, so use it to bind the click. Here you are binding it for each button each time you click on any button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's alerting more than once is because you are delegating the same event multiple times, use event-delegation like this and remove the `onclick="test(this)"` on the element

```
$(document).on('click','.btnprint',function(){
 var row  = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
 var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
 alert(row);
});
```

Comment: Please add a suggestion to replace `.attr('id')`. It's no `$(this).attr('id');`, but too damn close xD

Comment: @Cerbrus sry, what do you mean? :P

Comment: Hm, actually, that might not really apply here. I 'm talking about just using `.id` instead.

Comment: @Cerbrus Ah yeah, OP wants to get the row parent id, then we must get the dom element to use .id

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can call the button two times 1) onclick="test(this)",2)button click

```
 function test() {                   
                    var row  = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
                    var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
                    alert(row);
                 }
```

other wise u can use delegation .. @Anton posted method

```
$(document).on('click','.btnprint',function(){
 var row  = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
 var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
 alert(row);
});
```

Comment: thanks hey i can even output the text within the table as well with alert(rowtext);

Answer (score -1):

```
function test() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btnprint', function () {
        var row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
        alert(rowtext);
    });
}
```

Comment: This will cause the same problem because you are binding the event multiple times on the same element.

Comment: No i have removed the onclick event inside button and i have have wrapped everything with the test function and just called the test function in the document.ready

Comment: The thing is if you call test() more than once it will cause the problem you had from the start, why not just use it on page load? btw why did you answer your own question when you've got an answer, just wondering

Comment: I only called test() once in the document.ready only,its no where else withing the code